# access a specific field within a query that is part of a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get an understanding of what the syntax would be to access a specific field within a query that makes up a subform within another form.
Form > SubForm/Query > Field

The field I am trying to get access to a field called Berthed that operates as a Boolean field.  Either the vessel is present or it is absent.

This is what I was trying and it does not work.

```
Me.Boat_Move_Prior_Week.SourceObject.berthed
```

In this case here is the breakdown

> Me = current form
>
> Boat_Move_Prior_Week = query
>
> Berthed = field I am trying to access through the VBA

My final goal will be to create an If statement, that upon requery of the Form, will look at the Berthed field, and if the field is checked (vessel is present) do nothing, but if the field is unchecked (vessel is not present) then remove the vessel from the query.

Answer (score 2):

To reach the field (on the subform) bound to the field *berthed*, this is the syntax (assuming the textbox on the subform also is named *berthed*):

```
IsBerthed = Me!NameOfSubformControl.Form!berthed.Value
```

Comment: Ok, I've added the following      If Me!Boat_Move_Prior_Week.Form!BERTHED.value = "" Then
            Me.Boat_Move_Prior_Week.SourceObject = ""
    End If      It's not coming back as an error, but I don't think I've got the correct value for the berthed field in the event the field is now unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Here an amazing guide to know how to deal with controls in main form and subforms:

[Link](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my syntax issues I should have been using False for the value.  Thanks to the two posters above for getting me in the right direction.

```
If Me.Boat_Move_Prior_Week.Form!BERTHED.value = False Then
        Me.Boat_Move_Prior_Week.SourceObject = ""
End If
```